# DLL settings file location

Tags: vb.net, application-settings

I have a Visual Studio 2008 solution, which has 5 projects, 4 of them are Class Libaries (DLL's). Those DLL have settings (User scope). The solution compile in a common output path, except the DLL.config files are not output to this folder. Everything works great, but I want the customer to be able to change settings in the DLL by editing the XML file. I have check in AppData\Local, but can't find anything.

Does someone can help me find the location of the files of each DLL's settings?
thanks a lot for your time and help

Comment: Thats not how it works.  A DLL usually doesnt have settings to begin with.  Since a DLL can be used by many many apps, it wont save to its own config file. You'll find any new, non default values in the `user.config` for the app - this allows a different set of settings for each app it is used with.  You'll probably regret letting users edit it directly

Comment: As the link explains, the settings file location is based on the **App** credentials - a DLL is a part of the app using it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It makes a lot of sense. I will change way those parameters are passed to the DLL.